# Round Slider - set a higher value to the min-handle and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, round-slider

This is my current implementation of a roundslider (docs: http://roundsliderui.com/). I need to be able to choose values Nov-Mar for example. Any ideas?

```
$("#round").roundSlider({
  sliderType: "range",
  min: 1,
  max: 12,
  tooltipFormat: function(args) {
    var months = ["", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
      "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul",
      "Aug", "Sep", "Okt",
      "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    return months[args.value];
  },
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="round" class="rslider"></div>
```

Scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css">
```

Comment: It seems to not done for this use case

Comment: Can it be done with normal jquery-ui sliders? Because I'm pretty sure that you can use the same implementation here.

Comment: Hum no you can't, it's a slider you can select a range between min and max that's all ... if your min is 0 and our max is 10, you can't choose a range like 9 to 3 ...

Comment: I guess your code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/y851xhjy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the **roundSlider 1.3** version, there is a property "***_invertRange***" added internally to allow the invert range selection. I hope, by enable this property you can achieve your requirement.

Please check the below demo, and update whether this helps you:

### [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/674/)

Comment: This was the EXACT solution to my problem, thank you!